# Incomplete OnDrawCell calls in TStringGrid with RangeSelect

Tags: delphi

I have a StringGrid with `goRangeSelect` enabled and my own `OnDrawCell` procedure.
But when I start to select multiple rows using the shift and down key I have the problem that `OnDrawCell` is only called for the first column of the row, where my selection was before I pressed any key.

The problem with this is that I draw a rect around the focused cell which I need to remove, so I need an `OnDrawCell` for every column of the old row.

Is it somehow possible to get `OnDrawCell` events for every column or can I solve this problem somehow else?

Here are some exmaples to demonstrate this behavior. I use Delphi 7:

I place a TMemo and a TStringGird on an empty form. In the TStringGrid I activate goRowSelect and an event handler for OnDrawCell with the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.fGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
   memo1.lines.add(format('Row: %d, Col: %d',[Arow,Acol]));
end;
```

Now I select the first row and press shift+cursor down. After the first cursor down I get in to memo:

```
Row: 1, Col: 1   <---- Only the first col of row 1 is painted. Instead of all cols
Row: 2, Col: 1
Row: 2, Col: 2
Row: 2, Col: 3
Row: 2, Col: 4
Row: 2, Col: 1
```

After 3 more shift+cursor down I get the following picture. You see that the dotted lines are still there except on the first col (red arrows).

[Error http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2351/I4DUPK.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2351/I4DUPK.jpg)

When I repaint the whole grid, this is corrected:

[AfterRepaint http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3766/jvyLg4.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3766/jvyLg4.jpg)

Comment: `OnDrawCell` if fired for every `Cell`, you might show your code for painting and selecting.

Comment: I added an example, I hope its more clear now.

Comment: You are right, this looks like a internal bug in the decision when a cell has to be repainted. With `goRowSelect` the handling of fragments of the prior painted focusrect is not handled. A workaround might be a call like `TStringGrid(Sender).Invalidate;` in the OnSelectCell event.

Comment: Invalidate works. I found out that it is enought to Invalidate the first and last row of the selection: `Grid.InvalidateRow(Grid.Selection.Bottom);
 Grid.InvalidateRow(Grid.Selection.Top);`